# CSS float property only working with extra style tags

Tags: css, css-float

There is something I guess I just don't understand about HTML css. When I use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>STC </title>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
...
.loginHeader{
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
}
.navLinks{
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topBar">
<div class="navLinks">
<a href=""> Home</a> | <a href=""> About</a> | <a href=""> Suggestions</a> | <a href=""> Terms & Conditions</a>
</div>
<div class="loginheader">
        croberts | <a href="/myContracts/">My Contracts</a> | <a href='?logout'>Logout </a>

</div>
</div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

My float right doesn't work the way I want it to. But if at the very beginning of my file, before the doctype declaration, I add `<style></style>` then it works perfectly. So why would something like that have any affect on that particular style? Everything else looks the way it should, it's just the float right problem.

Comment: everything looks fine, when I copy-paste your code, your loginheader div looks at right side of the page that is expected so what actually problem is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the 'H' of the `.loginheader{}` in your css you have 'H' and in HTML you have 'h'

Corrected >> http://jsfiddle.net/4eDAm/

Comment: and this is why I hate camelcase for HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that everything would look the way you would expect it to when adding content before your DOCTYPE is that you're throwing the document into Quirks Mode.